# cant receive e-mail from Gmail {postfix & dovecot}

Tags: email, gmail, postfix, dovecot

i just finish setup an e-mail account using postfix and dovecot out of the Plesk control panel.

i tested it with sending an e-mail to myself, and it worked,
but when i tried sending from my GMail account, i did not receive anything

this is my postfix conf:

```
    readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.11.5/README_FILES

inet_protocols = all
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
tls_medium_cipherlist = HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
myhostname = host.mydomain.com
message_size_limit = 10240000
```

i got to declare that this server uses a lot of domain names, and the e-mail i opened is a diffrenet domain than what listed in `myhostname = host.mydomain.com`
can this be realated?

Comment: Postfix logs and the gmail 'undeliverable message' email should contain a lot more additional information. Could you post them?

Comment: Technical details of temporary failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain yourwebcatalog.com by mail.mydomain.com. 

The error that the other server returned was:
454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem

Comment: Ok, so, is your TLS configuration correct? Does postfix have any errors in the logs about TLS? Is the `/etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem` file OK?

Comment: mmm.... i dont have any .pem file in /etc/postfix/

Comment: and the /var/log/maillog does not shows anything weird

Comment: Well, there you go. I guess Google can show you the rest of the way ;)